# Rotation Support: restrictions except one

Tags: ios, rotation

I have an issue.

All of the pushed view controllers must have 'smaller' (narrow) orientation mask than one controller.

Description:
Navigation controller push controllers. Let's say that we have ordinary controllers and special controller (or group of special controllers).

Ok, there are several groups with different supported orientations.
'Landscape Both', 'Portrait Both', 'All','AllExceptUpsideDown', 'Portrait'
Let's suppose that group with 'smaller' (narrow) orientation mask is a major group of controllers.

How should I properly set orientations in that case (major group of controllers have smaller mask of orientations)?

Original Task:
All of the pushed view controllers have 'Portrait' orientation. Special controller (one controller) is a member of 'AllExceptUpsideDown' group.
How should I properly set orientations to this group of controllers?

Am I right that Apple use intersection method in determining supported orientations? (Navigation controller supported orientations intersect with pushed view controller supported orientations)